# How to get this Pinterest style floating bottom nav bar with swipeable tabs? either Compose or XML for Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I am looking for nav bar which floats on the bottom and for the tabs to be swipe able. How can this be achieved for android. Compose or traditional kotlin/java - both works

[For example - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1yz.jpg)

Comment: https://uniqueandrocode.com/floating-bottom-navigation-bar-android/. This should be exactly what you need.

Comment: it works but with an exception - swipe sideways to change screens does not work. any idea about it? thanks!

Comment: Try looking at [viewPager](https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/). You'll have to adapt it to work with the bottom navbar. Let me know how that goes.